# How can a Double.parseDouble crash my app?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning java and i have found a great tutorial on youtube, when trying to addapt it for my needs, i came to this problem:

I need to turn a string into a double, do some math, and fill a TextView with the result.

Also, it would be nice, if i could get that data from the firebase database (which my code does in another activity).

Now, i've abandoned the ideea of getting the data from the dtb because the app crashes everytime i open the activity, after i added the try, catch, finally, it doenst crash, but the activity is blank and no error is being displayed.

Tried eliminating row by row, to see where the problem is, but the app still crashes, even if one row is being left in.

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText sup =  findViewById(R.id.etSup);
                EditText emi =  findViewById(R.id.etEmi);
                EditText ver =  findViewById(R.id.etVer);
                EditText abs =  findViewById(R.id.etAbs);
                TextView ResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
                TextView Car =  findViewById(R.id.tvCar);
                Double dsup = Double.parseDouble(sup.getText().toString());
                Double demi = Double.parseDouble(emi.getText().toString());
                Double dver = Double.parseDouble(ver.getText().toString());
                Double dabs = Double.parseDouble(abs.getText().toString());

                Double CE = dsup * demi;
                ResultTextView.setText("Total emissions are " + CE);

                Double PS = dver * dabs;
                Double Total = CE - PS;
                Car.setText("Emission balance is " + Total);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
}
```

}

---

No error messages have been seen

Comment: `Double.parseDouble` will throw an exception if the string is empty. Do your edit texts have empty strings? If so, that's why your app is crashing.

Comment: step by step debugging

Comment: In addition to @Sweeper's comment, you also need to add validation that the string you are trying to parse to `Double` is a `Numeric` string, else your app will crash again with `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Use "Logcat" to debug and see the errors.

Comment: @Sweeper, how could i make the code jump over them if the string is empty?

Comment: You can't just jump over them, because you are using them in your calculation later. If `sup` is empty, what should be the value of `dsup`? 0?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the entirety of the onClick() method in a try/catch block. By the time a parseDouble() method throws an exception, you are no longer in the onCreate() method because all you are doing in onCreate() is registering a listener. The onClick() method runs later on

I'm not sure what exception you might be getting from your parseDouble calls (could be many things, nullpointer perhaps?) but this change will allow you to find out.

In case I'm not explaining myself very well:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            // do things
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Changed catching 'Exception' to 'Throwable' just to be sure we don't miss anything (as a side note, you really shouldn't catch a Throwable except for debugging, which is why I've thrown it on again)

Comment: I did, but still, the try catch doesn't return anything

Comment: Then for some old school debugging try adding 'System.out.println("I am at step x")' after each call. This will tell you for sure where the code stops executing. It's odd that the inner try/catch doesn't report anything, try also changing that 'Exception e' to a 'Throwable e' just to be sure